# Android sending SMS with value back to a mobile automatically ( in background)

Tags: android, sms

After My android app is able to retrieve a token from a web application, I would like to know how to make it send the token through a SMS to a normal mobile device ( e.g. Iphone, Nokia) ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code,

```
public class SendSMS 
{
    public static void sendsms(String address,String msgContent)
    {
        try
        {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            ArrayList<String> smsString = sms.divideMessage(msgContent); 
            sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(address, null, smsString, null, null);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm listening value from a web application, not android. so once I get the value from the web app I would need to retrieve it and send the value through SMS to a mobile device.

Comment: ok got it. so after receiving value from web application you need to check it and send sms. here where are you getting problem ?

Comment: the part I didn't know how to is that, how do I send the sms?

Comment: So this can be send in background? without using any UI am I right? I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: yes, you can. and hey , please accept the answer if it is helpful for you. so it can be helpful for others.

Comment: hey lucifer have tried it does not work on mine, unable to send the sms.